# How can I have multiple promises manipulate the same DOM element as a side effect with consistent results?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, dojo

I have the following Dojo 1.9 code that loads 2 tables asynchronously (some names changed):

```
function loadPanel1() {                                              

    // set 'Loading Tool' status message                                                     
    var actionStatus = dom.byId("globalError");                                              
    var oldStatus = actionStatus.innerHTML;                                                  
    var oldStatusClass = actionStatus.className;                                             
    actionStatus.className = "globalInfo";                                                   
    actionStatus.innerHTML = globalInfoMessage                                               
            + loadingMessage;                                                  

    // Post the data to the server                                                           
    request                                                                                  
            .post("loadPanel1.action", {                                     
                data : {                                                                     
                    "projectOid" : projectOid,                                               
                    "oid" : projectStreamOid                                                 
                }                                                                            
            })                                                                               
            .then(                                                                           
                    function(response) {                                                     
                        if (CommonUtils.checkForLoginPage(response)) {                       
                            return;                                                          
                        }                                                                    

                        dom.byId("Panel1").innerHTML = response;     

                        // restore previous action status                                    
                        var actionStatus = dom.byId("globalError");                          
                        actionStatus.innerHTML = oldStatus;                                  
                        actionStatus.className = oldStatusClass;                             
                        connectLinks();                                                      
                    },                                                                       
                    function(error) {                                                        
                        if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {                                  
                            location.reload(true);                                           
                        } else if (error instanceof Error) {                                 
                            var actionStatus = dom                                           
                                    .byId("globalError");                                    
                            actionStatus.innerHTML = globalErrorMessage                      
                                    + loadingErrorMessage;                     
                            actionStatus.className = "globalError";                          
                        }                                                                    
                    });                                                                      
}

//connectLinks connects event handlers to several links in Panel1 that reload the panel using loadPanel1() when successful.

/**                                                                                          
 * Posts the search form criteria to the server via ajax call.                               
 */                                                                                          
function loadPanel2() {                                               

    // set 'Loading Tool' status message                                                     
    var actionStatus = dom.byId("globalError");                                              
    var oldStatus = actionStatus.innerHTML;                                                  
    var oldStatusClass = actionStatus.className;                                             
    actionStatus.className = "globalInfo";                                                   
    actionStatus.innerHTML = globalInfoMessage                                               
            + loadingMessage;                                                  

    // Post the data to the server                                                           
    request                                                                                  
            .post("loadPanel2.action", {                                      
                data : {                                                                     
                    "projectOid" : projectOid,                                               
                    "oid" : projectStreamOid                                                 
                }                                                                            
            })                                                                               
            .then(                                                                           
                    function(response) {                                                     
                        if (CommonUtils.checkForLoginPage(response)) {                       
                            return;                                                          
                        }                                                                    

                        dom.byId("Panel2").innerHTML = response;      

                        // restore previous action status                                    
                        var actionStatus = dom.byId("globalError");                          
                        actionStatus.innerHTML = oldStatus;                                  
                        actionStatus.className = oldStatusClass;                             
                    },                                                                       
                    function(error) {                                                        
                        if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {                                  
                            location.reload(true);                                           
                        } else if (error instanceof Error) {                                 
                            var actionStatus = dom                                           
                                    .byId("globalError");                                    
                            actionStatus.innerHTML = globalErrorMessage                      
                                    + loadingErrorMessage;                     
                            actionStatus.className = "globalError";                          
                        }                                                                    
                    });                                                                    
}
```

The problem I have is essentially a race condition:

1. loadPanel1 starts and caches the old status locally;
2. loadPanel1 shows a loading message in the status;
3. loadPanel1 starts loading the panel;
4. loadPanel2 starts and caches the loading message placed by loadPanel1;
5. loadPanel2 replaces the loading message with the same message;
6. loadPanel2 starts loading Panel 2;
7. loadPanel1 finishes loading the panel and places the old status it cached back;
8. loadPanel2 finishes loading and replaces the old status loadPanel1 placed back with the loading message it cached!

One complication is that sometimes, when the page loads, globalError already is showing a status, and that status should not be erased by either loadPanel method. So no matter if loadPanel1() or loadPanel2() finishes last, that status needs to be retained. In addition, Panel1 has several links themselves that can alter the contents of Panel1, in turn adding a status message and reloading the panel (after which the message should still remain). Panel2 doesn't reload once it's been loaded.

so there are several workflows:

1. Page loads without status message, both panels are loaded, and regardless of which one finishes when, no status message should show;
2. Page loads WITH status message, both panels are loaded, and regardless of which one finishes when, the original status message should remain;
3. Page and panels are loaded. The user performs an action that changes the internal state of panel1. The action shows a status message, panel1 is reloaded, and the status message shown by the action should remain after the panel is loaded.
4. Something goes wrong when loading a panel, in which case an error message should show as the status message, regardless of when, which and how many panels fail to load.

I can't help but think that there is an elegant solution for this using an external method to cache the action message, but Google doesn't really help me on this. Most articles on having multiple asynchronous loading with loading message involve displaying the loading message in the same location as the eventual content gets loaded into, which doesn't help in this case.

Comment: what about using dojo/promise/all https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/all.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with my coworkers for the best approach, I decided to have the asynchronously loaded components use a separate message display instead of trying to juggle the messages in the same display.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to have a single status message that you are going to replace. Instead, make it a list, to which every component can append, change, or remove its own messages. Your logic should be something like

```
load(x) {
    const message = MessagePanel.newMessage();
    message.setContent(loader);
    message.show();
    fetch(x).then(res => {
        if (res.isMessage)
            message.setContent(res);
        else
            message.hide();
    }, err => {
        message.setContent(err);
    });
}
```

After some timeout, or on user interaction, you'll want to hide the messages again so that the list doesn't grow infinitely.

If you really want/can show only a single message, make the `MessagePanel` manage the state. The `load` function should do exactly the same, but the panel might decide to show only the top message in the list, or the one that was most recently shown.